# The Matlab code for the K chart - what does x mean?

Tags: matlab, class, classification, svm

I found the paper
"Performance evaluation of one-class classification-based control charts through an industrial application" (Gani, Limam), In:
Quality and Reliability Engineering International, 29, pp. 841–854, 2012

The appendix of this paper contains Matlab code for the K-chart algorithm. I have tried to run this code, but I am facing some trouble.

```
% show the KD of each training observation    
KD_training = W*offs - 2*sum(repmat(W.a',n,1) x K_training,2);
```

Can anybody explain me what the `x` stands for?! Is it a cross product or something different?! If it represents the cross product, the Matlab function couldn't apply it to the 60x60 double matrices:

```
u = repmat(W.a',n,1);  %60x60 double
v = K_training;        %60x60 double
z = cross(u,v);
```

A and B must have at least one dimension of length 3.

I can't run this code, I always encounter errors here. Thank you for your help!

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qre.1440/pdf

Comment: I think that `x` means nothing but simple matrix product. You can do that by `z=u*v`.

Comment: It looks like they included Matlab code that was typed "dry", without actually running it. :( – In such cases, it's always best to directly ask the corresponding author of the paper. His email can be found here: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qre.1440/abstract